# How can I download new content in a HTML script?

Tags: html, scripting

How can I download new content in a HTML script? More specifically, I'm looking for a way to update a page without it being completely reloaded. I have searched Google to no avail. Most probably I don't know the proper search query to enter.

My home project is a chat site with "lazy loading" or "infinite scrolling" content from input of its users.

Two side questions:
Is the best application for this project PHP, Java, or something else?
How is a Javascript paused without blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper search query is "ajax".

Normally one would use PHP for your requirements, but I would suggest to use a programming language you are already comfortable with.  I.e. if you already know Java then use it.

For a "techy-er" chat app, you may research on "server push"

Comment: "Server Push" seems like the way to go. I'm already familiar with Java. However, Microsoft support may be an issue. According to the site http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/, "If the server is busy or slow, the application will hang or stop." On the other hand, I'm unsure if I want so many Java Sockets open at once.

Comment: Why would Microsoft support be an issue? We've developed a server push framework based on Comet approach, and it's working fine even in Microsoft IE.  You may want to check out the Comet approach or this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728020/best-solution-for-java-http-push-messaging

Answer (score 0):

AJAX/XMLHttpRequest is what you are looking for. A small example using JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('#some-container').load('http://example.com/');
```

PHP is probably the way to go here. Asynchronous calls in JavaScript are implemented using callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

Making a chat script will require some kind of server side language, I highly recommend PHP.
The combination of ajax/PHP should give best results. Json long polling is also good